# PUBSUB CHANNELS returns empty list

Tags: python-2.7, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a python programme as below

```
import json
import threading

import redis

CHANNELS_PREFIX = 'client'


class Listener(threading.Thread):
    STOP = 1
    CONTINUE = 0

    def __init__(self, r):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.redis = r
        self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
        self.pubsub.psubscribe(["%s:*" % CHANNELS_PREFIX])

    def reload(self, data):
        print "Reloaing", data
        return Listener.CONTINUE

    def shutdown(self, data):
        self.pubsub.unsubscribe()
        print "unsubscribed and finished"
        return Listener.STOP

    def run(self):
        for item in self.pubsub.listen():
            print item
            type = item['type']
            if type == 'psubscribe':
                continue
            data = item['data'].strip()
            channel, method_name = item['channel'].split(':')
            method = getattr(self, method_name)
            if method is not None:
                if method(data) == Listener.STOP:
                    break


class Publisher():

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.redis = r

    def key(self, command):
        return "%s:%s" % (CHANNELS_PREFIX, command)

    def send(self, command, data):
        self.redis.publish(self.key(command), json.dumps(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Listener(redis.Redis())
    client.start()

    publisher = Publisher(redis.Redis())
```

When I execute this and try to find the list of channels in my Redis server using redis-cli using "PUBSUB CHANNELS" getting an empty list, how to list all the channels.
The programme works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PUBSUB CHANNELS
>
> Lists the currently active channels. An active channel is a Pub/Sub channel with one or more subscribers (**not including clients subscribed to patterns**).

Your code uses `PSUBSCRIBE` command and subscribes to a pattern, NOT a channel, so `PUBSUB CHANNELS` returns an empty list.

Also, you can take a look at the [PUBSUB NUMPAT](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub#codepubsub-numpatcode) command, which returns the number of patterns.

Comment: My understanding was PSUBSCRIBE Subscribes to messages broadcast to channels that match the given pattern. Is there any command to list all the patterns and to find the number of subscribers to each pattern